# how to remove backslashes in json URL with php

Tags: php, json

i need to remove () backslash in my string when using `echo json_encode()`?

my example..

```
$song_url = 116e9155e0afc11555cf33dc9c9bd25d.mp3
$resmsg[] = array("Song_name"=>"$song_name","Song_URL"=>"http://www.kbmusique.com/songs/$song_url");
echo json_encode($resmsg);
```

my output is

```
 [{"Song_name":"djigh araouioui","Song_URL":"http:\/\/www.kbmusique.com\/songs\/116e9155e0afc11555cf33dc9c9bd25d.mp3"}]
```

but i need as

```
 [{"Song_name":"djigh araouioui","Song_URL":"http://www.kbmusique.com/songs/116e9155e0afc11555cf33dc9c9bd25d.mp3"}]
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to remove them? They `\/` is a perfectly valid way to express a forwards slash in JSON.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Why do you need this? Probably there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: no i just need to test this url in my project so i need to copy this song url and paste it directly to the browser so wat i asked?

Comment: No no while json_encode it use forward slash to escape // no problem in that. When you use json_decode or other cross platform server json parse method will work perfect.

Comment: @sanja can u explain some more?

Comment: @Nes i understood that concept but i need to remove that backslash 4m my url to test my another file .. is ter anyway to get that?

Comment: The question is how you parse the output that PHP generates? The backslashes are, as @Quentin said, the correct way to escape a slash in JSON. Parse the output using any JSON parser and the escaped slashes should be looking ok. You should also make sure the Content-Type header is application/json. Not sure what you mean by "dynamic URL".

Comment: Hi Still i dont understand your next step :)

Answer (score -1):

Your comment indicates that you just need to get a copy/pastable URL for testing.

Just parse the JSON and extract the piece of data you need from it. i.e. If you want a text representation of something, then convert the JSON to text, don't try to hack the JSON into a specific form.

You could do this in PHP with `json_decode`, in a browser with `JSON.parse()`, or just use a tool such as the Chrome [JSONView extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc).

Comment: is ter anyway to remove backslashes in json_encode() itself.,